# TLS 1.0 off impact on SharePoint 2013/CA/InfoPath-2010 and SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath

Does turning off TLS 1.0 on SharePoint 2013 Servers have any impact? 
We use Infopath 2010 forms on those servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does.  We have an InfoPath form that populates various dropdowns with database table queries and if we turn off TLS1.0 those queries stop working with an error message of: "The form cannot connect to the data source. [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()).]SSL Security error.)”.

I have followed the guide to enabling TLS and SSL support but there must be another step required for InfoPath support that I have so far been unable to find.

Comment: Ok, how about disabling at client browsers and still keeping it on, on all SharePoint Servers in a FARM. Did you get a chance to check this case?

Comment: The farm is what I'm referring to.  I disabled TLS1.0 on the web front end servers and it broke the InfoPath form.  As soon as I turned it back on again the form started working again.  The form works fine with TLS1.0 disabled on client browsers.

Answer (score 3):

There is a series of steps you must follow to enable support for TLS 1.1 and/or TLS 1.2. Once you complete these steps, you should be fine.

[Enable TLS and SSL support in SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-and-ssl-support-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: We are still using info path 2010 and SharePoint designer 2013, Info path will not have any impact with those changes?

Comment: Designer definitely has no impact. InfoPath shouldn't have an issue, but it is worth testing. It's pretty easy to enable/disable higher/lower versions of TLS should you encounter any issues.